# How to apply a rate on a aggregated measures

Tags: sql-server, database-design, ssas, cube

I'm currently designing a new measures into my cube. The logic is quite simple :

I have a measure which is the number of page loaded on my site (a count of rows in the table PageLoad).

And I have a data which is : a page loaded on a given month is worth 0.01 cents for example.

My structure is as follow :

Fact_PageLoad -> Dim_Calendar -> Dim_PricePerPage

And I need the measure Page Loaded Earning (which is : count of row * rate)

And now I'm wondering how I can implement this data. I thought of a calculated member. But even if this is possible how SSAS is gonna handle it if I ask it to give me how much I earned between the 15 august and the 15th of september whereas the august rate is 0.01 and the september rate is 0.05 ? Will it be able to count the august row and multiply them by 0.01 and add it the count of september rows multiplied by 0.05 ?

I thought of another solution which should work : add a calculated field in my PageLoad table which is simply the rate. And then I simply have to sum this field. But I'm not sure it is the best solution.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I fully understood your question but based on my speculation, two tables and a piece of code should do the job. Its more of a logic side problem than database design side.

Store each hit in one table with the time stamp. Store monthly rate in another table.

When a request of calculation is made, calculate number of hits for 1 months, multiply with the month rate, calculate number of hits second month and do the same and add them. I don't see any other way when there is a rate variation.